# Циклится программа при большом размере динамического массива

Tags: c, алгоритм, динамические-массивы

В программе записан алгоритм "Решето Эратосфена". Проблема в том что, при достаточно больших n (таких как n=1000000) программа зацикливается, и я не могу понять, где здесь проблема. Вот, собственно, сама программа:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int n,p,j=3;
    bool check;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    if(n%2) 
        n=n/2+1;
    else
        n/=2;
    int *a=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
    a[0]=2;
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        a[i]=j;
        j+=2;

    }
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        p=a[i];
        check=false;
        for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
        {
            if((a[j]%p)==0)
            {
                for(int k=j;k<n-1;k++)
                    a[k]=a[k+1];
                check=true;
                n--;
                j--;
            }
        }
    if(check==false)
        break;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%d ",a[i]);
    free(a);
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Если вы видите `%p` в коде, то это не ["решето Эратосфена"](http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf). Вот [пример на c++](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#C.2B.2B) и на Питоне [sieve_of_eratosthenes(limit) (для читаемости)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20782064/4279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Программа не  зацикливается. Она работает как ожидается. Более того, при 1000000 (то есть 1 миллион, оно же 1кк) оно даже досчитало. Другое дело, что считало оно долго. И это ожидаемо - в Вашей реализации сложность кубическая. Я позапускал Ваш код с разными входными n и померял время выполнения. Получил такое

`n    - sec
100k - 3
200k - 8
300k - 16
400k - 25
500k - 40
600k - 56
700k - 78
800k - 100
900k - 126
1000k - 157`

Попросим [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=fit+%7B(100,+3),(200,+8),(300,+16),(400,+25),(500,+40),(600,+56),(800,+100),+(1000,157)%7D) подобрать сложность. Все подтвержается - кубическая.

Если посмотреть на [примеры](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/eratosthenes_sieve), то там обещают сложность `O(n log log n)`, что очень даже не плохо. По моим оценкам, я бы смог сходу реализовать `O(n*n)` (то есть, квадратичную). Вам же удалось сделать её кубической и запутанной (я честно не понимаю, что там происходит внутри).

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, убедитесь в том, что в `int` на вашей платформе влезает значение `1000000`.

Во-вторых, при правильном размере целого не циклится. Просто у вас очень неэффективная реализация, которая неприлично долго работает при таких значениях.

Comment: я позапускал несколько раз программу - она не писала, что 25 простое.

Comment: @KoVadim, да, что-то сглючил.

Answer (score 2):

Как бы это выразиться... Вы сделали почти все, чтобы затормозить решение вашей задачи :)

Вот - с тем же расходом памяти.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int n,j;

    scanf("%d",&n);
    if (n >= 2)
    {
        printf("2 ");
    }
    else return 0;

    bool *a=(bool *)malloc(sizeof(bool)*((n+1)/2));
    for(j = 0; j < (n+1)/2; ++j) a[j] = true;

    for(j = 3; j*j <= n; j += 2)
    {
        if (a[(j-3)/2] == false) continue;
        for(int i = 3; i*j <= n; i+=2)
            a[(i*j-3)/2] = false;
    }

    for(j = 3; j <= n; j+=2)
        if (a[(j-3)/2]) printf("%d ",j);

    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

На моей машине - 46 миллисекунд против 35 секунд вашей программы (в 760 раз)...

Answer (score 0):

Для начала, убедитесь, что malloc не вернула вам 0.