# Алгоритм нахождения простых чисел Pascal

Tags: алгоритм, pascal

Задача: найти все простые числа, не превышающие заданного. Ниже код. Не могли бы вы проверить нет ли там ошибки. Я не совсем уверен что он работает корректно. Буду благодарен.

```
Program Lab_4;
var
  i, n, range : integer;
  Flag : boolean;
Begin
  i := 0;
  n := 0;
  write('Введите диапазон: ');
  read(range);
  while i < range do 
  Begin
    Flag := True;
    n := 0;
    i := i + 1;
    while n < i - 1 do
    Begin
      n := n + 1;
      if ((i mod n = 0) and (n > 2)) or ((i mod 2 = 0) and (i <> 2)) then
        Flag := False;
    end;
    if Flag then
      writeln(i, ' - Простое число!');
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Ну попробуйте поискать числа больше 2^128 и посмотрите...

Comment: Боюсь, они не влезут в integer.

Comment: Я уже это заметил(

Comment: Проверять делимость достаточно до квадратного корня, округлённого вниз.

Comment: ... и только на простые числа. Не далее как сегодня уже одну программу пришлось писать. [Взгляните](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/638824/195342), может, и поможет - правда, не на Pascal'е писано...

Comment: @КириллМалышев, вверх, либо round. из-за тонкостей плавающей точки можно зацепить какой-нибудь квадрат.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот, посмотрите. Что-то вроде такого должно быть.

```
program Lab_4;

var
  i, n, range: integer;
  Flag: boolean;

begin
  i := 1;
  n := 0;
  write('Введите диапазон: ');
  read(range);
  while i < range do 
  begin
    Flag := True;
    n := 1;
    i := i + 1;
    if i <> 2 then
      while n <= sqrt(i) do
      begin
        n := n + 1;
        if i mod n = 0 then begin
            Flag := False;
            break;
        end;
      end;
    if Flag then
      writeln(i, ' - Простое число!');
  end;
end.
```

Answer (score 3):

Иногда бывает гораздо проще код просто переписать. Тогда повысится его читабельность.

Зачем Вы используете цикл `while` когда здесь нужен `for`, я не понял. Ну и как правильно заметили, проверять делимость нужно не до самого числа, а до его квадратного корня.

Итого:

```
program Lab_4;
var
  i, n, range : integer;
  Flag : boolean;
begin
  write('Введите диапазон: ');
  read(range);
  for i := 2 to range do begin
    Flag := True;
    for n := 2 to Trunc(Sqrt(i)) do begin
      Flag := i mod n <> 0;
      if not Flag then
        break;
    end;
    if Flag then
      writeln(i, ' - Простое число!');
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Вы правы на счет цикла for. Я уже сделал этим способом. У меня задание сделать циклами: while, for, repeat.

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете проверить свою программу на наличие ошибок в автоматизированной системе. Например, [здесь](http://informatics.mccme.ru/mod/statements/view.php?id=634). 
Правда, ввод/вывод программы понадобится адаптировать для тестирующей системы, но это просто.

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться идеями [Сундарама](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE_%D0%A1%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0), суть которых проста и логична.

1. Просеивать только нечётные числа. Т.е. элемент решета `a[m]` должен содержать число `m` и соответствовать числу `2m+1`.
2. Исключить из массива все числа вида **i+j+2ij**, поскольку `2(i+j+2ij)+1` = `(2i+1)(2j+1)`.
   Этого достаточно, поскольку все составные нечётные числа являются произведением нечётных чисел.
3. Границы по меньшему индексу `i` определяются условием **(2i+1)<sup>2</sup> ∈ [3, 2M+1]**, где `M` - размерность массива `a`.
   Т.е. **i ∈ [1, sqrt(2M+1) / 2 -1 ]**
4. Границы по большему индексу `j` определяются условием **i+j+2ij ∈ [1, M]**.
   Т.е. **j ∈ [1, (M-i) / (2i+1)]**.
5. Перебор по `i` и `j` проводится с шагом 1.
6. Значения `m`, полученные в результате отбора, следует пересчитать в простые числа по формуле **p=2m+1**.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/149926)

Comment: Вот честно, ничего интересного в статье нет. Автор сам в теме не разобрался... В комментариях инфа есть, но чтобы её понять нужно явно больше опыта иметь чем ответ на этот вопрос найти

Comment: @cheops Спасибо, учёл.

Comment: @pavel Согласен, так и есть. А с другой стороны - на ruSO тема решета Эратосфена обкатана вдоль и поперёк. Хватит уже изобретать велосипеды,

Answer (score -1):

Данное решение может быть и длинное, но работает
UPD: обновлено по просьбе aleksandr barakin

```
program stack;
function simple(x:int64):boolean;
begin
    if((x=2)or(x=3)or(x=5)or(x=7)or((x mod 2<>0)and(x mod 3<>0)and(x mod 5<>0)and(x mod 7<>0))) then simple:=true
    else simple:=false;
end;
var i,n:int64;
begin
Write('N = '); ReadLn(n);
for i:=1 to n do 
    if(simple(i))then WriteLn(i,' - Простое число');
end.
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Интересно, с каких пор 9 стало простым числом. Ну и после 100 уже фактически не работает нормально.

Comment: Ладно, недочет. А если убрать эту девятку, то все равно не работает?

Comment: Это не решение.

Comment: Это решение с очень ограниченной областью, где оно корректно работает, фактически от 2 до 120. От 121 и до 3569 есть 320 чисел, которые простыми не являются, но ваша функция их таковыми считает. На алгоритм нахождения простых чисел это явно не тянет.