# Как посчитать количество простых чисел в массиве?

Tags: pascal

Массив одномерный, заполнен натуральными числами. Как мне вычислить количество элементов, которые являются простыми числами?

Например, `[1, 8, 9, 11, 21, 5, 1024, 77777]` ответом будет 3 - `{1, 11, 5}`

Comment: В чем заключается вопрос?

Comment: Связанный вопрос - [Алгоритм нахождения простых чисел Pascal](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/638994/%d0%90%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb-pascal)

Comment: 1 простым числом НЕ является.

Answer (score 1):

1. Найти максимальное число в исходном массиве и найти все простые числа от `1` до `max` (либо заранее подготовить и подключать массив с простыми числами). Как найти простые числа подсказали в комментариях.
2. Пройтись по исходному массиву и сравнить, содержит ли массив простых чисел число из исходного массива.
3. Можно без расчета простых чисел обойтись. Вот [несколько алгоритмов](http://ru.wikihow.com/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C,-%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BC), с помощью которых можно определить, является ли число простым.